# using a getter to get an Object out of an ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I am working on a Bank system exercise for class and i have a get function to get an Account object out of an ArrayList using the account id, it looks like this:

"Account" is a class, 
"accounts" is the ArrayList, 
"id" is a one of the values of the Object Account

```
public Account getAccount(int id){


    for (Account account : accounts) {
        if(((Account)account).getId()==id){
            return  ((Account)account); 

        }
    } 

}
```

however the function claims that there is no return statement (i work on Eclipse and that is the error it shows me) logcally it seems fine to me so i must have a syntax error of some sort, can anyone please spot my mistake?

thank you!

Comment: Because if there is no account in your list with such an id, you return nothing.

Comment: Why are you casting `account` to `Account` when it already has static type `Account`? (If `accounts` is a bare `ArrayList` rather than `ArrayList<Account>`, make it an `ArrayList<Account>`.)

Comment: you should add a return statement out of for scope, in case it didn't don't found matching id.

Comment: Why wouldn't you just use a `HashMap<Integer,Account>` instead of the list?

Comment: @DavidWallace i dont want to use a key-value technic here, this is why i use ArrayList

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you define a return value you have to deliver one:

```
public Account getAccount(int id){
    Account found = null;
    for (Account account : accounts) {
        if(((Account)account).getId()==id){
            found = ((Account)account); 
            break;
        }
    } 
    return found;
}
```

or

```
public Account getAccount(int id){
    for (Account account : accounts) {
        if(((Account)account).getId()==id){
            return ((Account)account); 
        }
    } 
    return null;
}
```

found can be null in my example but you will always return Account or null.

btw. You should use a generic list like that:

```
    List<Account> accounts;
```

the advantage is that there is no typecast necessary.

Comment: Better to add a return statement inside the loop and return null at the end of your method. If you found already an account with the given id, no need to loop through the rest of the elements in the list.

Comment: so this code looks great, problem is i check it and even when i try to get an account that defenitly exist and has that id, it still returns null..

Comment: then there is no account with the id.

Comment: @StefanBeike i had initianted an account with this id just to check it, 'Account account1 = new Account(9, 120);' where the constructor is:
public Account(int id, float balance){
  this.id = id;
  this.balance = balance;
 }

but when i run in the program System.out.println(client1.getAccount(9));

it still prints null

Comment: did you use a debugger?

Answer (score 0):

The only way your function will return something is if the account with that particular ID exists in the list. You need a return statement that deals with the case where the account with that particular ID doesn't exist. Having said this, multiple return statements are generally bad practice so I recommend something like this:

```
public Account getAccount(int id) throws AccountNotFoundException{

    Account acc = null;
    for (Account account : accounts) {
        if(((Account)account).getId()==id){
            acc = (Account) account;
        }
    } 
    if(acc == null) throw new AccountNotFoundException();
    return acc;

}
```

Comment: Thank you for the edit, David. I was just about to do the same thing :P

Comment: 1. This code doesn't compile 2. If you want to throw an exception, better to do `for (Account account : accounts) {
         if(account.getId()==id){
             return account;
         }
     } 
     throw new AccountNotFoundException();`

Comment: @ZouZou Hi! Sorry it didn't compile. It could be because you don't have the `Account` or `AccountNotFoundException` classes defined. Could you tell me what went wrong?

Comment: No I assumed that thoses classes were well defined. But you have not initialized the `acc` variable.

Comment: @Zouzou Ahh of course! Sorry about that. I've initialized it as `null` now.

Answer (score 0):

Its expecting an Account object to be returned "independent of any conditions".. You return Account only if

```
if(((Account)account).getId()==id){
            return  ((Account)account);
```

add `return null;` at the end of the function...

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a return statement after the for loop.

Also, you don't need all these brackets in your code.

```
public Account getAccount(int id){
    for (Account account : accounts) {
        if (account.getId()==id){
            return account; 
        }
    } 
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 Account temp=null;

    if(((Account)account).getId()==id){
    temp=(Account)account); 
    }
    return temp;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have make sure you return `null` if no account matches the id passed.

```
public Account getAccount(int id){

        for (Account account : accounts) {
            if(account.getId()==id){
               return (account); 

            }
        } 
    return null;

    }
```

Comment: this the corrct code, thank you, but it still returns null even when i try to get an existing account i had instansiated for this test

Comment: @ZivKesten can u share the entire code of the account class and where you are trying to fetch it. just edit your question. also remove those unnecessary account casts.

Comment: check after creating an account did you make sure you put it in the list of accounts?